# How to create a "yes/no" answer based on multiple variables

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a formula to display "PASS" or "FAIL" based on 5 other columns' information.
As long as the numbers in the 5 other columns all meet or exceed the minimums needed then it should display "PASS".
If any of the columns do not meet the minimums then it should display "FAIL".

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Putting up a sample of a formula will help those answering point you in the right direction.

Comment: =IF(AND(L6>10(AND(J6>65(AND(K6>65))))),"P","F")   This is what I've tried thus far.  It only has 3 of the 5 parameters because the other 2 involve time with a colon used and it keeps thinking i'm referencing other cells and not the minimum value i'm trying to reference.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried this (Spanish version) and it works:

`=SI((CONTAR.SI(J6;">65")+CONTAR.SI(K6;">65")+CONTAR.SI(L6;">10"))=3;"PASS";"FAIL")`

I think in the English version this should be:

`=IF((COUNTIF(J6, ">65")+COUNTIF(K6, ">65")+COUNTIF(L6,">10"))=3,"PASS","FAIL")`

Comment: It's COUNTIF without the dot in English. (And comma for separating arguments, since the decimal separator is a dot.)

Comment: Wow!  That worked fantastically!!!  Thank you so much!!!  One last question, how can it be modified so that if all of the data cells are blank that the "PASS/FAIL" cell displays blank?  as its written right now if any of them are blank it displays "FAIL"

Comment: This formula works well in Spanish:

=SI(NO(Y(ESBLANCO(J6);ESBLANCO(K6);ESBLANCO(L6)));SI((CONTAR.SI(J6;">65")+CONTAR.SI(K6;">65")+CONTAR.SI(L6;">10"))=3;"PASS";"FAIL");"BLANK")

The formula in the English version should be:

=IF(NOT(AND(ISBLANK(J6),ISBLANK(K6),ISBLANK(L6))),IF((COUNTIF(J6,">65")+COUNTIF(K6,">65")+COUNTIF(L6,">10"))=3,"PASS","FAIL"),"BLANK")

Comment: ran into a snag, heres what i'm currently using:              =IF(NOT(AND(ISBLANK(J8),ISBLANK(K8),ISBLANK(L8))),=IF((COUNTIF(I8,"<9:31")+COUNTIF(J8, ">65")+COUNTIF(K8, ">65")+COUNTIF(L8,">11")+COUNTIF(M8,"<10:01"))=5,"P","F"),"BLANK")       this formula gets me an error msg saying "formula parse error"  any ideas?

Comment: I think the principal mistake is here: **"... =IF((COUNTIF( ..."** you have to remove the sign **"="**, and I believe that this condition does not work: **"... (I8,"<9:31") ..."**

Comment: Tried removing the "=", nogo...

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned which columns nor what the minima are I am assuming the relevant columns are A:E with the minima in Row1:

```
=if(sumproduct(A$1:E$1<A2:E2)=5,"Pass","Fail")
```

[SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294) counts the number of columns in which the minima are exceeded and [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) checks whether or not that is all five.